# NuGet has problems with missing packages, how to restore?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

When I try to compile my program I get the following error:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567.
```

Now when I right click on the solution and press

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
```

I tried manually reinstalling every package which didn't solve the problem, I tried reinstalling NuGet but that didn't help either and I even tried reinstalling visual studio.

I also tried moving the package folder from the tfs folder to overwrite my package folder but that didn't solve anything.  I also tried redownloading them with this package missing, that didn' t solve the problem either.

Anybody know how to restore the nuget packages?

Answer (score 31):

Use `Package Manager Console` in Visual Studio to run this command.

1.This will [restore all packages](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore) from solution

```
nuget restore YourSolution.sln
```

2.If you want to [reinstall the packages](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages) to the same versions as were previously installed

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

Comment: nuget restore TestEnvi.sln give me the error The term 'restore' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script

Comment: That suggests that installing nuget commands would be simply running 

    Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine
 but that gives me 'Package 'NuGet.CommandLine.3.4.3' already exists in project 'TestEnvi''

Comment: Did you try `Update-Package -reinstall` command in package manager console

Comment: That runs for a bit and then throws the error ' The item 'packages.config' cannot be deleted '

Comment: There's one work around for this. In your solution folder there should be a "packages" directory. Open this directory and delete all the directories and then run again reinstall.

Comment: Hmm running it a second time it did complete, but I still canot run the restore command (nuget not recognized) and the problem persitsts.

Comment: Try deleting whole `packages` folder from solution and then run `Update-Package -reinstall`

Comment: An unexpected error is keeping you from deleting the folder. if you continue to receive this error you can use the error code to search for help with this problem. Error 0x8007000F: The system cannot find the drive specified. So I cannot delete the folder in question

Comment: I doubt you have file access permissions issue or corrupted drive. You need to check your OS and computer system. It has nothing to do with nuget

Comment: Any advice how to deal with these? The file sits on an veracrypt encrypted file so shouldn' t that sort of auto detect problems?

Comment: You need to check your OS and computer system. It has nothing to do with nuget. sorry its out of my knowledge.

Comment: I will if it turns out that this is indeed the problem. I'm currently looking into the filesystem. But it looks like this is going to help seeing as how there are 3 files that cannot be removed as a admin cmd.

Comment: I managed to remove the packages folder (had to specify thoese 3 files by hand) and when ran the program which resulted in the package folder being downloaded again. However the problem remains unchanged.

Comment: The command `nuget restore mysolution.sln` doesn't work for me in the Package Manager Console window, I get this error: "`PM> nuget restore reco.sln
nuget : The term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`"

Comment: This worked partly, I also had to add references manually, it was a mix of all the steps

Comment: Thank you, 1st running this : Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine
then the above did the trick for me

Comment: @NickG. That didn't work either. Maybe `Install-Package NuGet` ?

Comment: 'Update-Package -reinstall' helped me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 26):

Honestly, whoever developed the NuGet command for VS needs to go back to the drawing board.  They totaly missed the fact that sometimes these DLL(s) and/or files get corrupt or deleted.  a "NuGet Get-Packages -Force" option would really save their bacon.  The only GAP I see is that VS and the Package console does not allow you to invoke a forced download from NuGet.  Even clearing the cache via VS is useless.

Comment: Too frigging right. One workaround for this is to uninstall the packages form your project then reinstall them. Sucks.

Comment: It's the year 2020 and this is still broken

Comment: 2022 and counting.

Comment: 2023 and counting.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this issue when I tried to build my project on a computer where the packages-folder did not already exist in the solution root.

When the project file was initially created, it seems VS2019 added the following into the project file:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
</Target>
```

From what I understand those settings are deprecated nowadays, no idea why VS inserted it in the first place.

Anyway, after removing those lines VS restored the packages and built the solution correctly again.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me. No clue why this reference was placed in my project file.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a good idea to clear the Nuget Cache by deleting the contents within this directory: `C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Local\NuGet`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't solve the problem (even after rebooting VS)

Comment: In my case, I had to clear this directory and `C:\Users\{your_username}\.nuget\packages` for the issue to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is that:
Open the Package Manager Console and run this command: `Update-Package -reinstall`

**P.S**: VS2017 and above NuGet Package Manager is included with Visual Studio, no need to install anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the functionality of the NuGet package can also be caused by the fact that *NuGet package is requiring certain dependency that the project does not meet*.

NuGet package can have a declared dependency in **Dependecies** section, e.g. .NETFramework,Version=v.4.6.2 while the project is targeted to an older version (**Target framework: .NET Framework 4.6.1.**).

Instead of the NuGet system notifying the user of this fact, the project simply does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have different Nuget configurations, and somehow the HintPath in the project file didn't fit.

[image]

Maybe you should check if the HintPath leads to the right NuGetPackages folder.

You should also check the following entries at the top of the file:
[image]

And at the bottom of the file:
[image]

All these paths should point to the right NuGetPackage folder in your file structure.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was solved by deleting the "obj" folder(s) and then rebuilding the solution.

The "obj" folder had several NuGet related files that still referred to version 0.0.2 of a package while all projects in the solution were already using version 1.0.0 of that package. Building the solution failed with the error message "package with version 0.0.2 could not be found". The solution with build folders included was recently copied from another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's probably a bad way but I found that it works if I just delete the line

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567." HelpKeyword="BCLBUILD2001" />

from the project.csproj , not sure if this is going to cause problems later on but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tried deleting the bin and obj folders, restarting VS, restarting my PC but to no avail. However, running

```
dotnet restore
```

fixed the issue